# Proving arrangement is impossible in a square.

Tags: combinatorics

We have a square $a,b,c,d$ with  $1$ chip on each vertex. A move consists in removing $1$ chip from one vertex and adding $2$ chips to an adjacent vertex. Is it possible to reach configuration $a=2014,b=2013,c=2015,d=2014$? I'd say it isn't, but I can find an invariance or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing a chip from one vertex and adding two chips to an adjacent vertex doesn't change $(a+c)-(b+d)$ (mod $3$).  This invariant is $0$ in the initial configuration and $2$ in the target configuration; so the target configuration isn't reachable.

Comment: nice, I had been playing around with this but didn't land it. I guess I'll be satisfied with getting really close.